# Validation not working for radio button in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, radio-button

Validation not working for radio button in Angular.

When radio button is not selected, form is getting submitted.
Also not showing error.

**HTML Code**

```
<form [formGroup]="feedbackFormWithArray" (ngSubmit)="submitData()">
  <table class="res-tbl">
        <tbody formArrayName="skills" class="tbl">
          <tr class="skill-tr table-data" *ngFor="let skill of skills; let i = index">
              <td class="table-data res-td tbl-border skill-td">
                <b value="skill.skillId"><span class="text-danger">*</span>{{skill.skillName}}<span>:</span></b><p class="skill-description-p"> {{skill.skillDescription}}</p> 
              </td>
              <td class="table-data center rating-td">
                <input type="radio" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="3" />
              </td>
              <td class="table-data center rating-td">
                <input type="radio" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="2" />
              </td>
              <td class="table-data center rating-td">
                <input type="radio" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="1" />
              </td>
          </tr>
        
        </tbody>
        <div *ngIf="(submitted && skills.invalid)">
          <small *ngIf="skills.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Please select Skills</small>  
      </div> 
      </table>
  <Button type="submit"  [disabled]="feedbackFormWithArray.invalid" class="btn button-btn" >{{feedbackId ? 'Update' : 'Create'}}</Button>
</form>
```

**TS Code**

```
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

submitted : boolean  = false;

this.feedbackFormWithArray= this.fb.group({
 skills: this.fb.array(
        this.skills.map((t) => {
          this.fb.control(t);
        }), {validators: Validators.required}
      )
});

submitData() {
  this.submitted = true;
}
```

How to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: How to you trigger submission, there is no button for this in the example?

Comment: I have the button I have missed it here.

Comment: Can I show the validation failed error before submitting form?

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna guess you have a button inside your form, something like:

component.html

```html
<button (click)="submitData()">Submit</button>
```

You could add a check to change submitted state like

```
submitData() {
  if (this.feedbackFormWithArray.valid) {
     this.submitted = true;
  }

  if (this.feedbackFormWithArray.invalid) {
    // Do something like this.tryToSubmitWithError = true
    // Popup to say you cannot submit
    // ...
  }
}
```

I think also you wanted to use **feedbackFormWithArray** instead of **skills** in the `*ngIf` below:

```html
<div *ngIf="(submitted && skills.invalid)">
  <small *ngIf="skills.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Please select Skills</small>  
</div>
```

That could be like:

```html
<div *ngIf="tryToSubmitWithError && feedbackFormWithArray.invalid">
  <small *ngIf="feedbackFormWithArray.errors?.required" class="text-danger">
       Please select Skills
  </small>
</div>
```